# ECHO strange behavior when inside IF block

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, echo

I have a Windows Batch script named `test.bat` as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET name=Dan
SET greeting=Hi %name%, how are you?
ECHO %greeting%
```

When executed I get the following output:

```
Hi Dan, how are you?
```

This is what I would expected. I changed the script to the following:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
IF EXIST test.bat (
    SET name=Dan
    SET greeting=Hi %name%, how are you
    ECHO %greeting%
) ELSE (
    ECHO Nofile
)
```

I would expect to get the same output. Instead I get the following:

```
ECHO is off.
```

Please can someone help me understand why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need [delayed expansion:](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enableDelayedExpansion
IF EXIST test.bat (
    SET name=Dan
    SET greeting=Hi !name!, how are you
    ECHO !greeting!
) ELSE (
    ECHO Nofile
)
```

The batch files have two phases of reading the script - execution and parsing. During parsing phase all variables enclosed with `%` are substituted and during execution phase the commands are executed. With the delayed expansion turned on the variables enclosed with `!` will be expanded during execution phase (i.e. later)

Brackets on the other side (as well as `&`) puts the commands in a block taken as one single command so all variables with `%` are substituted during the first phase and when you are setting variables you'll need delayed expansion.

Comment: Are you able to elaborate? I'm more interested in understanding what's going than the solution.

Comment: @DanStevens - it is explained in the link , though I'll update the answer

Comment: That's great. Thanks!